# Mobile Hub Sample App Google Sign -in canceled if applicationId changes

Tags: android, google-plus, amazon-cognito

I am using the Sample App from Mobile Hub v0.16 and used it successfully for sign-in to google, userpools etc.
But when  change the applicationID in build.gradle(Module:app) from 
applicationId "com.amazon.mysampleapp" to something else the login with google does no longer work (Login canceled).

What is the reason for this? How do I change the applicationID in a way that the sign-in still works?

Follow-up:
For the cognito federated pool I set up  google credentials for

a) Web application with ClientID1

b) Android with ClientID2 where as commented by Jeff Solinsky the app package should be used

Where do these client IDs go? 
My understanding is that ClientID1 is used in the federated pool ->authentication providers->google+ ->google client ID

Then in the example app from mobilehub I put ClientID1 in AWSConfiguration.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID

Where does CLientID2 get used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the package name for your Google App's Android Package name in the Google backend. Navigate to the Google API Console under credentials (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). Find your Android client ID in the list and make sure the setting for it has the correct Signing-certificate fingerprint and package name for your app.

You must also ensure that the Android client ID is set in the IAM Console under Identity Providers. Specifically, under the provider "accounts.google.com" an audience should be set containing the Android Client ID. This is automatically performed for you by Mobile Hub when you have update your project by configuring the Google Android Client ID for the Google Sign-in Provider in the User Sign-in feature from Mobile Hub's Console.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I still have problems and modified he question to make it more understandable also for others.

Comment: I updated my response with details about where the Google Android Client ID is set in the AWS IAM Console.